# Align Text Vertically Inside Grid Item

Tags: css, grid

Aligning text vertically is always tricky.

The Following table **vertically aligns text inside a `<td>` tag.** I would like the replicate this behavior using CSS grids.

This Code snippet shows text that is vertically aligned by default CSS table:

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <pre>
        multi-line
        item
      </pre>
    </td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This code implements CSS Grid but does not vertically center the text inside the `<td>` tag.

```css
tr {
  display: grid; 
  grid-template-columns: auto auto; 
}

td {
  border: 2px solid red;
  vertical-align: middle; /* DOES NOT WORK */
  justify-content: center; /* DOES NOT WORK */ 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <pre>
        multi-line
        item
      </pre>
    </td>
    <td>Hello World</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.

Use `align-self` to align content inside CSS Grid item.

```
td {
   align-self: center;
}
```